# Unable to consume messages or only one message is getting retrieved while connecting to IBM MQ asynchronous?

Tags: java, websphere, ibm-mq

I had written a java code to consume messages from IBM MQ.. but while executing the code some times only one message is getting consumed and the process is stopping .. some times no messages are not getting consumed at all.. i  had written an asynchronous connection using setMessageListener() but i am not sure where the program is getting wrong. The below code

```
public class MQConnectivity implements MessageListener {
    
    MQQueueConnectionFactory factory = new MQQueueConnectionFactory();
    QueueConnection con;
    Queue queue;
    QueueSession session;
    QueueReceiver receiver;
    
    public void init() {
        try {
            factory.setHostName("******");
            factory.setPort(123);
            factory.setChannel("Channel1");
            factory.setQueueManager("queue_manager");
            factory.setTransportType(new Integer(WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT));
            con=factory.createQueueConnection("user1"," password1");
            queue= new MQQueue("myQueue");
            session=con.createQueueSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
            receiver=session.createReceiver(queue);
            receiver.setMessageListener(this);
            System.out.println("=======connection happened=========");
            con.start();
            System.out.println("=======connection started=========");
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("exception is : "+ex);
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        new MQConnectivity().init();

    }
    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message msg) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        try {
        System.out.println("Inside onMessage method");
        TextMessage txtMsg=(TextMessage)msg;
        System.out.println(txtMsg.getText());
        }catch(Exception ex) {
            System.out.println("error in onMessage"+ex);
        }
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

I can see two problems in your code.

1. There is no connection.Start() method call after setting message listener. Without calling connection.Start method, message delivery will not start. I wonder how application received message(s) without Start().
2. Your application is exiting immediately after

`"System.out.println("=======connection happened=========");"`.

Since onMessage method gets called on a separate thread, you need to make your main thread wait till message processing is complete.

Tweak your applications to something like:

```
   //... other code

   receiver.setMessageListener(this);
   con.start();
   System.out.println("=======connection happened=========");
   // Wait for a key to be hit.
   System.in.read();
```

Hope this helps.

**Further updates 8th July:**
You have two threads in your application:

1. Main thread that creates connection, consumer and a message listener. Attaches the message listener to a consumer.
2. Message listner thread - this is invoked by MQ libraries to deliver messages to your application.

The main thread controls the life cycle of your application. If that ends, all other threads in your application also end. Dont expect the message listner thread to run even after main thread ends. This is basic threading concepts, nothing specific to message listener. There is no issue here with message listener, it is working as designed.

JMS is an API specification only, not an implementation. Many vendors like MQ JMS implement the specifications.

Instead of using asynchronous consumer, you might want to use synchronous consumer.recieve() or consumer.receiveNoWait() methods on the main thread itself. These APIs retrieve messages if available or return null if there are no messages. You can check for null and exit.

Hope this helps.

Comment: :thanks for your reply.. i didnt added con.start()  in this code . but i do it in my actual code ..  still it is not consuming any messages.. As it is asynchronous call some times only one message gets consumed and the thread is getting stopped.. thats what i think if some where i am doing wrong

Comment: As per your second point the onMessage() call is not happening whatever the print statement i had provided it needs to be printed but not printing

Comment: Did you add a System.in.read(); in your code? It works perfectly fine for me. Instead of System.in.read() can you try with Thread.sleep(60000); to force main thread to wait for a minute? To me it looks like your main thread is exiting before onMessage could receive messages in the queue.

Comment: is there any other process instead of System.inread() to wait for some time till some message get consumed..

Comment: For test purpose you can use Thread.Sleep().

Comment: i had used Thread.sleep(15000) but only till that time the messages getting consusmed and stopping after that time completes.. but as per asynchronous process it should try to consume till last message gets loaded right

Comment: If your main thread terminates, thereby ending application, there's nothing much asynchronous consumer can do here. You have to write your application in such way that it waits till user ends it explicitly.

Comment: but what would be the issue and how can i know why my main thread is getting terminated without completion and this is happening in the case of MQ but not in the case of JMS.. there is no wait method any other inputs methods written in case of  JMS code but the asynchronous process runs successfully

Comment: See further updates in my answer.

Comment: How can i check message length in asynchronous process

Comment: You must read documentation